# Ratchet websocket responses do not change

Tags: angularjs, laravel, autobahn, ratchet

I am using ratchet websockets to connect to a WAMP Autobahn front-end.

Everything works perfectly however when I change the topic code, the responses do not change!

i am running this in docker, when I restart the containers the updates responses get sent but then if I change this again nothing happens!

Answer (score 0):

Your questions doesn't have many details but I think what is happening is your are running the PHP WebSocket server.  Then changing the PHP code and expect the server to automatically update.  That isn't how it works, you have to restart the websocket for code changes to take effect.

If you want to have a dynamic response without restarting the socket I suggest using a database or other data store that you can dynamically change and PHP can fetch from